# R grab element from list using [[ ]]

Tags: r

I have a list

```
MyList <- lapply(1:10, function(i) list(x=i, y=i^2))
```

that I can grab elements from using `function()`

```
sapply(MyList, function(i) i$x) ## works
```

that I would like to grab using brackets

```
sapply(MyList, [['x']] ) ## does not work
```

Bracket notation is more concise, but I do not know how to use sapply that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sapply` function needs a function as its second argument.

```
sapply(List, `[[`, 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `[[x]]` like a function you have to use `[[`.

So:

```
sapply(MyList, "[[", "x")
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Also you can use a more intuitively named function `getElement`:

```
sapply(MyList, getElement, "x")
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```